# Creating Outlook appointments recurring every 12 years

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a problem when trying to create Outlook appointment with recurrence every 12 years.  Exception is thrown as in snippet below:

```
var oa = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
oa.Subject = "Test";
oa.Start = new DateTime(2009, 06, 12);
oa.End = new DateTime(2009, 06, 13);
oa.AllDayEvent = true;
oa.ReminderSet = false;
var rp = oa.GetRecurrencePattern();
rp.RecurrenceType = Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursYearly;
rp.StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-12");
rp.PatternStartDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-12");
rp.EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-13");
try
{
   rp.Interval = 12 * 12;  //throws exception
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
//Exception is:
//Exception Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
//Error Code: A5120009
//Exception: The recurrence pattern is not valid.
//Source: Microsoft Outlook
//Stack Trace:
//   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern.set_Interval(Int32 Interval)
}
```

Few points:

1. I think Microsoft documentation is not correct here:

> When RecurrenceType is set to olRecursYearNth or olRecursYear, the Interval property indicates the number of years between occurrences. For example, Interval equals 1 indicates the recurrence is every year, Interval equals 2 indicates the recurrence is every 2 years, and so on.

My experiments show that for olRecursYear you need to specify Interval in months, so to achieve recurrence every 2 year, one need to put 24 into Interval field.

2. It is possible to specify every 12 years recurrence in Outlook GUI and if I retrieve such appointment in my code I am getting 144 (12*12) in Interval field.  The problem is to create such appointment from scratch in C# code.

Any help/guidance from Outlook APIs gurus?   Maybe I misunderstood something from Microsoft docs?

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: What exception is thrown? Please edit your question to include (at least the first few lines of) the exception text.

Comment: Edited to add more info about exception being thrown.

Comment: I don't remember what Outlook did in the older versions, but on the MAPI level, the recurrence blob always stored the interval in months for the yearly occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Checked under Outlook 2013 - just like Outlook 2016 and 2019, `RecurrencePattern.Interval` expects and returns months, not years.

So the behavior is the same, just the docs are wrong.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot put 144 into Interval field (12 years) as exception is being thrown.  What is correct way to create appointments which happen every 12 years?

Comment: And for documentation problem I have opened issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-outlook-pia-ref-dotnet/issues/14

Comment: Hmmm.. Yes, it looks like 96 (8 years) is the max. I can only offer to use Redemption - its RDOAppointmentItem object does not have this restriction.

Comment: The issue was found in Open Source project I am working with, so Redemption is not an option.

Comment: I can confirm this. I just ran into a bug in our calendar sync software and found this to be the case. I couldn't figure out why on earth it needed 12 instead of 1...